# Building a form for a like button in a polymorphic relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, social-media-like

I'm trying to build a form for a like button. This like model is polymorphic to different types of Models (comments / posts / etc.) and belongs to a certain user.

When this user is viewing a blog item for instance, I want to show a like button below the post. I've set-up my routes in a way that the like routes are always nested inside the polymorphic object for which they are destined:

So for posts for instance:

```
#routes.rb
resources :posts do
   resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

So a post link would look like `/posts/:post_id/likes/` (method: Post)

In the controller I create a new Like object, assign it to a user and save it. This works perfectly.

The problem is when I'm trying to create delete form. I really have no clue how to create that, I know the link should be `/posts/:post_id/like/:id` (method: Delete), but configuring it this way results in an error.

I think the form could also be refactored, but I have no clue on how making forms for these kind of 'complex' relationships.

```haml
#shared/_like_button.html.haml

- if not @post.is_liked_by current_user
  = form_for(@post.likes.build, url: post_likes_path(@post)) do |f|
  = f.submit
- else
  = form_for(@post.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id), url: post_like_path(@post), html: {method: :delete}) do |f|
= f.submit
```

I think the main problem is that `post_like_path(@post)` doesn't get rendered correctly because I'm not aware of the `:id` of the like. So I keep getting an `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` in `PostsController#show` error when trying to build the link.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Thanks, Sander's answer was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
= form_for([@post, @post.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)], html: {method: :delete}) do |f|
```

`url: post_like_path(@post)` in your code expects a second argument (the `like` object). That's what throws the error. 
But you don't need it actualy if you put the nested resources as an array in the first argument of the `form_for` helper.

> If the record passed to form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to
>   a set of RESTful routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in
>   config/routes.rb. In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate
>   URL from the record itself.
>   (source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

You can pass an array of resources if your resource is nested within another resource.

Now... You probably want to re-use this code for your other polymorphic models as well. You can do this by passing `@post`, or `@comment` to your partial like this:

```
= render :partial => 'like_button', locals: {likable: @post}
```

and refactor your partial like this:

```
= form_for([likable, likable.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)], html: { method: :delete}) do |form|
```

Comment: Great thanks! Could you explain what the multiple variables in the brackets [@post, @post.likes] are meaning?

Comment: When you nest routes, you need to pass all the objects to the url helper that have an :id in the route itself, so you are passing an array of all the objects defined in the route - for the create action it only needs a post (/posts/:id/likes), but for the delete it needs both a post and a like object (/posts/:post_id/likes/:id)

Comment: Great, thanks! One last question, after that partials I need to include some more partials (and even a .erb rendered partial from a ajax callback) and keep setting the same variable. Can I set the variable as a global is the first partial? @likeable = likeable?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use an actual form, you could do it with a link_to. Here's an example with basic text link (to make sure it's working)

```
- if not @post.is_liked_by current_user
  = link_to 'Like', post_like_path(@post), method: :post
- else
  = link_to 'Delete', post_like_path([@post, @post.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)]), method: :delete
```

Then you use an image/button as the link itself.

```
- if not @post.is_liked_by current_user
  = link_to post_like_path(@post), method: :post do
    # some html image/button
- else
  = link_to post_like_path([@post, @post.likes.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)]), method: :delete do
    # some html image/button
```

Updated this code with help from the accepted answer so anyone looking in future can use link_to.

Comment: I've already tried something like this, problem is that I keep getting a: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in PostsController#show error. Although the link shows up in my routes. Probably because the like :id is not being set! (and I don't need to, because I have all the information to delete the like)

Comment: Updated the answer with Sander's URL fix.